# Differential Equations: Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm supposed to find out whether or not the method of Undetermined Coefficients can be used to find a particular solution of
$$5y'' - 3y' + 2y = t^3 \cos4t.$$

I need to find out if there’s a finite family of derivatives, but I’m struggling with what I should make the initial guess be for g(x).

Comment: For the particular solution, I would make the guess $$\phi_p(t)=(At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D)\cos(4t)+(Et^3 + Ft^2 +Gt + H)\sin(4t).$$

Comment: Oh, that makes sense— thank you!!